# Vaadin one to many Grid binding and expanding child entity

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

There is the Customer entity which has a one to many relationship to entity Address,so there is a `List<Address> getAddress` in Customer.Entity Address has three columns,Street,City and Country.

So for instance to get the address details for one customer with two addresses you do

```
customer.getAddress.get(0).getStreet
customer.getAddress.get(0).getCity
customer.getAddress.get(0).getCountry
```

For the second address you do

```
customer.getAddress.get(1).getStreet
customer.getAddress.get(1).getCity
customer.getAddress.get(1).getCountry
```

Is there a way to display one row for the Customer details and display a sub-grid or (just dump the Address object's contents) that
expands the Address entity and shows the two address rows with the 3 columns?

In essence show the parent and expand the child.I was looking at TreeGrid but it requires a single type of bean like TreeGrid and I don't know how Address would fill into the picture.

Does the basic Grid have a feature like that? I see that you can add different types of columns with addComponentColumn,but is that only for UI elements,like adding buttons etc ?

Comment: Have you checked Grid's details row feature?

Comment: No,can you please provide me a link to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a `LitRenderer` for that, but displaying this much data in a grid would extend the height of a row a lot.

With `addComponentColumn` you can add any Component you want, like a single Button, Image or a more complex Layout that you created.

Like Tatu Lund suggested you can use the [ItemDetailsRenderer](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid/#item-details). There you can implement a `LitRenderer` or a `ComponentRenderer`. Then you can display all complex information about the customer.